# Multi tabbing of a struts application causing data inconsistency

Tags: java, struts, tabbing

I am using Struts 1.2.9 .The application is facing a problem when i am using multiple tabs.

Say when i am filling up the fields in each tab simultaneously , i am able to see data entered from 2nd tab's request number updated in DB for 1'st tab's request number.

Am not sure whether synchronizing the execute method for the action would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nutshell: no, but it also depends on what specifically you're talking about.

Struts 1 actions are like servlets: there is a single instance per action mapping. In general you almost *never* want to use instance variables to store any state. If your issue is with request-level data then the action(s) were coded incorrectly and instance variables should be eliminated.

If the issue is with session-level data it's harder to solve: In most browsers, tabs in the same browser window share sessions.

If you need to have multiple users in multiple tabs then you'd need to implement an additional layer of session scoping similar to JBoss Seam and similar.

Comment: Dave..In my application only one user is allowed for a session since we use wsl cookies for login.So the problem comes when the same logged in user opens 2 tabs with different product ids from the search results and does an update in another tab after doing a change in a different tab. So the data intended for one product id is updated in another product id, since both ids have same data fields and form values.

Comment: @ashwinsakthi Like I said, it's the same session across tabs. Any session data is shared between tabs. Either don't put the information in session, out implement some form of multiple conversations.